# mysql update left join time out - is there a better solution

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to move 25000 records from old table to a new table where the fields have different names.  The query times out.  What is the alternative?

```
UPDATE images AS A LEFT JOIN GW_xImage AS B on A.id=B.Image_ID 
SET 
A.created_at = B.Date_Created,
A.updated_at = B.Date_Modified,
A.is_active = B.Mark_Active,
... 30 more fields following;
```

Even with only the 2 first field, I get "#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction".

Here is a solution that is very fast:

```
INSERT INTO images (id, created_at, updated_at, is_active, is_image,
    is_private, is_default, rating, code, number, subfolder,
    title, caption, summary, location, subregion, region,
    country_id, gps, altitude, keywords, author, note, date,
    month, year, type, format, ratio, width, height, camera_body,
    camera_lens, camera_focal, camera_iso, camera_speed, camera_aperture)
SELECT Imgae_ID, Date_Created, Date_Modified, Mark_Active, Mark_IsImage,
    Mark_Private, Mark_Default, TotalStars, ShortCodeOrgan, Image_Number, Image_SubFolder,
    ImageTitle, Image, ImageNewTitle, Location, SubRegion, Region,
    Country_ID, LocationGPS, LocationAltitude, Keywords, Author, Note, Image_Date,
    Image_Month, Image_Year, Image_Type, Image_Format, Image_Ratio, Image_MaxWPx, Image_MaxHPx, Camera_Body,
    Camera_Lens, Camera_Focale, Camera_ISO, Camera_Speed,
    Camera_Aperture
FROM GW_xImage;
```

Comment: Make sure `images.id` and `GW_xImage.Image_ID` both are indexed

Comment: this query makes no much sense to me. If there is no corresponding row in table B all values in Table A will be set to NULL. If there are more then one rows in B matching the condition, A will be updated multiple times and just keep the last value. Is this the requirement? On the other side, if there is a row in B for each row in A, can't you just copy the whole table?

Comment: The rename the fields in the old table is not an option?

Comment: Both tables have 30+ fields but their names differ.  I have updated my post with the solution I found.  Thank your for your help anyway.

Comment: What's up?  The Question seems to present a solution involving `LEFT JOIN`, then a much better solution using `INSERT...SELECT`.  Is there anything left for us to do for you?

Comment: Be aware of what will happen to any `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Comment: @RickJames I totally agree.  In fact I forgot to copy the id field.  In my case the id was not incremented, so no problem.  Final solution edited in my original post.